# Php-fpm still logging my error even when using catch

Tags: php, fpm

Php-fpm error log file is still logging my error even using try-catch

```
$NUM_OF_ATTEMPTS = 100;
$attempts = 0;
        do
            {
            try
                {
                $db = new SQLite3('proxies/socks5.db');
                $results = $db->query('SELECT proxy FROM socks5proxies WHERE timeout <= ' . $settimeout . $countryq . ';');
                while ($row = $results->fetchArray())
                    {
                    echo $row['proxy'] . "\r\n";
                    }
                }

            catch(Exception $e)
                {
                $attempts++;
                sleep(1);
                continue;
                }

            break;
            }

        while ($attempts < $NUM_OF_ATTEMPTS);
```

### Expected result:

Retry on error, and don't log the error

### Actual results:

Logs the error in the php-fpm error log file:
      thrown in /var/www/html/api.php on line 200
      [10-Jan-2019 14:00:49 UTC] PHP Warning:  SQLite3::query(): Unable to prepare statement: 11, database disk image is malformed in /var/www/html/api.php on line 140
      [10-Jan-2019 14:00:49 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetchArray() on boolean in /var/www/html/api.php:141
      Stack trace:
      #0 {main}
        thrown in /var/www/html/api.php on line 141

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [SQLite3::enableExceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.enableexceptions.php) to tell PHP it should throw exceptions instead of standard errors:

```
try {
    $db = new SQLite3('proxies/socks5.db');
    $db->enableExceptions(true);
    $results = $db->query('...');
} catch (\Exception $e) {
}
```

In any case, if you need to do 100 attempts to get this to work, then this really isn't the angle you should be taking to fix it.

Comment: normaly it wouldnt use the 100 attempts, only 3 i just made it 100 just in case

Comment: Let me rephrase: If you need to do more than 1 attempt to get this to work, then this really isn't the angle you should be taking to fix it. Fix the problem, not the symptom.